# How to find the files which is the problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

how to find the problematic file

```
rake aborted!
       Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "... filter: progid": expected ";", was ": DXImageTransf..."
       (sass):19792
       /tmp/build_ba581d6ed1d202133833b6c534904469/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1308:in `expected'
```

Comment: Have you tried `grep -rn 'DXImageTransf' app/assets`?

Comment: I comment this ligne because it was only for IE6/9

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer

Answer (score 0):

You can find that string if it exists in your assets directory by running the following from your project root:

```
grep -rn 'DXImageTransf' app/assets
```